# Rails routes redirect for both a single and wildcard path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

In my Rails app's `config/routes.rb` I’m trying to redirect any url that is or starts with `/support` to `/contact`. So a user going to `/support/a/b` would redirect to `/contact/a/b` and going to `/support` would redirect to `/contact`.

So far this is possible with two routes like the following:

```
get '/support*all' => redirect(path: '/contact%{all}')
get '/support' => redirect(path: '/contact')
```

My question is, is it possible to have one route that behaves like the above two routes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parenthesis are used to make a segment optional:

```
get '/support(/*all') => redirect(path: '/contact/%{all}')
```

But `redirect()` will produce an error if `all` matches nothing, i.e. when the path is `/support`.  In that case, the redirect path will be literally `'/contact/%{all}'`--no substitution is done.   So you need to provide a default value for `all` (note that `defaults:` is an argument for the `get()` method):

```
get '/support(/*all)', to: redirect(path: "/contact/%{all}"), defaults: {all: ''}
```

You can also provide a block for the `redirect()` method, and the return value of the block will be used as the redirect path:

```
get '/support(/*all)', to: redirect {|path_params, req|  #Cannot use do-end to delimit this block.
  "/contact/#{path_params[:all]}"
}
```

The thing to note about the block solution is that when `all` doesn't end up matching anything in the path, then there will be no entry for `all` in the params Hash, therefore `path_params[:all]` will return `nil`. Subsequently, when you interpolate `nil` into a String, [nil.to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s) is called, which returns a blank string.

Comment: @Simon Franzen, *Did not see your answer while I was answering.*-- Ah.  No worries.

Comment: Awesome, I'l try this out! Will report back about how it went.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks @7stud! I went with the passing in the `defaults` hash. The block example may come in handy for me later. Thanks for including it!